# SVG embed bug in Safari forces me to look for another option

Tags: vector, svg

I'm building an interactive website for a touchscreen, which runs the latest version of Google Chrome. The user has to tap on, in this case, a series of buildings to get more information about it. The idea is to absolute position hyperlinks and place them on top of the buildings, which are combined in a single background image. But as you can see below, the problem is that some hyperlinks overlap. The chance that the user taps on the wrong building without knowing, is quite large.

Because I already have the vector masks of each building, I thought it would be a good idea to not use hyperlinks, but use SVG files instead. SVG files support a tag called xlink, which you can use to make a vector object linkable. The clickable area which links to another file is not a square anymore, but has the same shape as the vector mask. So just like I did with the hyperlinks, I placed them on top of the buildings. This works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome nor Safari! Apparently there's a bug in Webkit (bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22986) which causes the browser to always show a white background and which neglects the shape of the vector object, so it's rendered as a square object.

[**Screenshot:** Overlapping hyperlinks and Webkti SVG Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp6vE.png)

*Normally the opacity of the SVG embed would be set to zero, but to show you what's going wrong I've set it to 1.*

Using Firefox instead is not an option. And the area-tag in HTML takes too much time. So I'm stuck. **Does anyone know another solution for this particular problem?**

Comment: Is the issue occuring with 1 svg file or do you make an svg file for each building? Could you make 1 svg file covering the whole page. Can you embed the images in the svg file? Could you embed the svg in the html (not as an external file)?

Comment: Thanks DiggyF for your response, but I've just found the solution for my problem. It seems that Illustrator added a tag named clipPath to the XML structure of the SVG file. This caused the xlink to be shaped as a rectangle in Webkit, and not as the path I wanted it to be. This doesn't solve the white background bug in Webkit, but that's not a problem anyway, because I'm setting the opacity of the SVG to zero. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to transform masks to `<path>`s
2. Create `<a><path/></a>` after all svg code (strict condition for Safari!)
3. Set `<path>`s `opacity` and `fill-opacity` to 0

Don't forget `<a>` target attribute